# MVVM Экранная клавиатура и ввод в разные TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть окно-форма авторизации, 2 TextBox и кнопка Login, для этой формы нужно сделать экранную клавиатуру, которая будет вводить данные тот TextBox, на который нажали. Как это можно сделать на WPF, в рамках паттерна MVVM?

View:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PadVol2.Views.Pages.RegUserPage"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PadVol2.Views.Pages"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

<Viewbox>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="50">
        <Grid >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Text="Номер пользователя:" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  Foreground="White" Margin="0,0,5,5" Height="16" Width="118" />
            <TextBox x:Name="login" Text="{Binding UID}" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0,0,5" Height="18" MaxLength="2"/>



            <TextBlock Text="Пароль:" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Grid.Row="1" Foreground="White" Margin="0,5,5,0" Height="16" Width="44" />
            <PasswordBox Name="passwordBox"   Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,5,0,0" Height="18"/>

            <Button Command="{Binding Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=passwordBox}" Content="Войти" Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="1" Width="75" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,28,0,0" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Width="40" Command="{Binding AddCharLogin}" CommandParameter="1" Height="40" Content="1"  Margin="2" FontSize="20" />
            <Button Width="40" Command="{Binding AddCharLogin}" CommandParameter="2" Height="40" Content="2"  Margin="2" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="20" />
            <Button Width="40" Command="{Binding AddCharLogin}" CommandParameter="3" Height="40" Content="3"  Margin="2" Grid.Column="2" FontSize="20" />
            <Button Width="40" Command="{Binding AddCharLogin}" CommandParameter="4" Height="40" Content="4"  Margin="2" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="20" />
            <Button Width="40" Command="{Binding AddCharLogin}" CommandParameter="5" Height="40" Content="5"  Margin="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="20" />
            <Button Width="40" Command="{Binding AddCharLogin}" CommandParameter="6" Height="40" Content="6"  Margin="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" FontSize="20" />
            <Button Width="40" Command="{Binding AddCharLogin}" CommandParameter="7" Height="40" Content="7"  Margin="2" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="20" />
            <Button Width="40" Command="{Binding AddCharLogin}" CommandParameter="8" Height="40" Content="8"  Margin="2" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="20" />
            <Button Width="40" Command="{Binding AddCharLogin}" CommandParameter="9" Height="40" Content="9"  Margin="2" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" FontSize="20" />
            <Button Width="40" Command="{Binding DelLogin}"  Height="40" Content="Удалить"  Margin="2" Grid.Row="3" FontSize="8" />
            <Button Width="40" Command="{Binding AddCharLogin}" CommandParameter="0" Height="40" Content="0"  Margin="2" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="20" />
            <Button Width="40" Command="{Binding ClearLogin}" Height="40" Content="Очистить"  Margin="2" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" FontSize="8" />
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>


</Viewbox>
```

ViewModel:

```
   class RegUserPageVM :ViewModelBase, IPageViewModel
    {
        public string UID { get; set; } = "";
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public ICommand Command { get; set; }
        public ICommand AddCharLogin
        {
            get
            {
                return new DelegateCommand<object>(x =>
                {
                    UID += x.ToString();

                }, CanAddCharLogin);
            }
        }
        private bool CanAddCharLogin(object param)
        {
            return this.UID.Length < 2;
        }
        public ICommand DelLogin
        {
            get
            {
                return new DelegateCommand(() =>
                {
                    if (UID.Length > 0)
                        UID = UID.Substring(0, UID.Length - 1);
                });
            }
        }
        public ICommand ClearLogin
        {
            get
            {
                return new DelegateCommand(() =>
                {
                    UID = "";
                    
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: А стандартная системная экранная клавиатура чем плоха?

Comment: В моем случае ее использовать нельзя

Comment: Пин-код чтоли? Что там должно быть на этой самой экранной клавиатуре, у вас есть интерфейс? Покажите разметку интерфейса. Допустим ли при этом ввод с обычной клавиатуры?

Comment: Программа будет грузиться при старте ОС, как оболочка, ввод с клавиатуры недопустим. Интерфейс это кнопки от 1 до 9, кнопка подтвердить и 2 текстбокса для логина и пароля

Comment: А вы что-нибудь уже сделали, или сделать за вас с нуля?

Comment: @aepot, ну сейчас у меня эта клавиатура вводит только в поле логина,  с паролем вообще беда, у PasswordBox не делается Binding к свойству в ViewModel'и

Comment: Так вы покажете свою разметку и код, или будем гадать?

Comment: _у PasswordBox не делается Binding к свойству_ - [биндить открытый пароль небезопасно](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1493330/12888024), я бы передавал пароль в команду, которая логинит пользователя как аргумент.

Comment: @aepot  добавил код в описание

Comment: И вообще, клавиатуру эту хотелось бы сделать отдельным элементом, потому что эта форма авторизации не единственная, где мне пригодится клавиатура

Comment: Ужаснейший UX, я бы вас проклял за такое приложение. WPF - это десктоп, а на дексктопе принято использовать клавиатуру и мышь, тут нету сенсора и других приблуд со смартфонов. Это попросту не удобно, да и безопасности это вам не даст. Ну, если так хочется, то рисуйте эту самую клавиатуру в виде контрола отдельного, сделайте ему DP, которое будет привязано к некому свойству в VM слое, а все доступные для ввода поля, привяжите к `IsFocused` например и вот у вас уже есть свойство и событие, которое показывает что сейчас выбрано, осталось дело за малым - привязать это все.

Comment: В том то и дело что это для сенсорного экрана планшета, там нет ни мыши, ни клавиатуры

Comment: Значит вам надо искать решение со стороны OS для решения данной проблемы, а не городить свои велосипеды. Вон к примеру [режим киоска](https://youtu.be/kgaWVsUPaV0?t=741) в Windows 10, да и просто планшетный режим, при клике на текстовое поле выскакивает снизу сенсорная клавиатура, ибо это задача OS взаимодействовать с пользователем, а вас, как разработчика это особо не должно волновать, вы должны лишь предоставить это самое текстовое поле. Так что мнение у меня то-же, это ужаснейшее UX решение, спасибо за такое вам явно не скажут.

Comment: Вы же сказали, что вам нужно запретить ввод с клавиатуры, или я не так понял? Кстати, я уже частично написал для вас решение, но есть еще несколько проблем, которые надо решить, и смогу выложить в ответ. Но вопрос про ввод с клавиатуры актуален, потому что это сильно влияет на механику работы текстбоксов.

Comment: Запрещать ввод с клавиатуры не обязательно, но обязательно производить ввод не экранной клавиатурой. Ну и соответсвенно нужно чтобы эта экранная клавиатура не всплывала. EvgeniyZ говорит про решения со стороны ос на эту тему, но кроме как экранной клавиатуры я ничего не нашёл, а клавиатура, на которой можно прожать ctrl+shift+esc, мне не подойдёт

Comment: @hiraeth Ну и что что ctrl+shift+esc, настройте политики в ос, поставьте нужные ограничения.

Comment: Это не единственная причина. Эта комбинация клавиш понадобится при подключении физической клавиатуры, так же у планшета не очень большой экран. Да и требуется клавиатура, на которой есть только цифры

Comment: _чтобы эта экранная клавиатура не всплывала_ а вот это я уже не знаю, как сделать. Задизаблить текстбоксы если только. Но тогда не будет курсора при вводе, это ок?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как задача специфична, без код-бихайнда обойтись не удалось, но удалось реализовать то, что нужно. Я сделал в рамках обычного окна, но вы можете распределить логику по юзер-контролам, это не должно составить труда.

Я не использую внешние библиотеки и классы для **MVVM** реализаций, вместо этого использую 2 следующих вспомогательных класса, думаю, вы знаете, что они делают:

```csharp
public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute = null)
        => (_execute, _canExecute) = (execute, canExecute);

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        => _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);

    public void Execute(object parameter)
        => _execute(parameter);
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```csharp
public class MainViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private const string _deleteText = "Удалить";
    private const string _clearText = "Очистить";
    private const int _loginLength = 6;
    private const int _passwordLength = 4;

    private string _uid = string.Empty;
    private string _password = string.Empty;
    private ICommand _keyPressCommand;
    private ICommand _loginCommand;

    public bool LoginFocused { get; set; }
    public bool PasswordFocused { get; set; }

    public string Uid
    {
        get => _uid;
        set
        {
            _uid = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Password
    {
        get => _password;
        set
        {
            _password = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PasswordView));
        }
    }

    public string PasswordView => new string('\u25cf', _password?.Length ?? 0);

    public ICommand KeyPressCommand => _keyPressCommand ?? (_keyPressCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        if (parameter is int number)
        {
            if (LoginFocused)
                Uid += number;
            else if (PasswordFocused)
                Password += number;
        }
        if (parameter is string command)
        {
            switch (command)
            {
                case _deleteText:
                    if (LoginFocused)
                        Uid = Uid.Remove(Uid.Length - 1);
                    else if (PasswordFocused)
                        Password = Password.Remove(Password.Length - 1);
                    break;
                case _clearText:
                    if (LoginFocused)
                        Uid = string.Empty;
                    else if (PasswordFocused)
                        Password = string.Empty;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, parameter =>
        (parameter is int && ((LoginFocused && Uid?.Length < _loginLength) || (PasswordFocused && Password?.Length < _passwordLength))) ||
        (parameter is string && ((LoginFocused && Uid?.Length > 0) || (PasswordFocused && Password?.Length > 0)))
    ));

    public ICommand LoginCommand => _loginCommand ?? (_loginCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Uid: {0}{1}Password: {2}", Uid, Environment.NewLine, Password));
    }));

    public IEnumerable<object> PadKeys => GetKeys();

    private IEnumerable<object> GetKeys()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            yield return i;
        yield return _deleteText;
        yield return 0;
        yield return _clearText;
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```csharp
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly MainViewModel _vm;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _vm = new MainViewModel();
        DataContext = _vm;
    }

    private void LoginBox_FocusChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is TextBox textBox)
            _vm.LoginFocused = textBox.IsFocused;
    }

    private void PasswordBox_FocusChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is TextBox textBox)
            _vm.PasswordFocused = textBox.IsFocused;
    }
}
```

Разметка адаптивная, можно менять размер окна, размер кнопок подстроится под любое разрешение. Настройте себе марджины и паддинги по вкусу.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Width="600" Height="300" FontSize="20" FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=LoginTextBox}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5">
            <TextBlock Text="Номер пользователя:" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="LoginTextBox" Margin="0,5" Text="{Binding Uid, Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True" GotFocus="LoginBox_FocusChanged" LostFocus="LoginBox_FocusChanged"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Пароль:" Margin="0,5,0,0" />
            <TextBox Margin="0,5" Text="{Binding PasswordView, Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True" GotFocus="PasswordBox_FocusChanged" LostFocus="PasswordBox_FocusChanged"/>
            <Button Content="Войти" Padding="20,5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PadKeys}" Grid.Column="1">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Margin="5" Command="{Binding DataContext.KeyPressCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Focusable="False" >
                        <Button.Content>
                            <Viewbox Margin="5">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                            </Viewbox>
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="3"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое