# WPF экранная клавиатура для ввода в элемент ChromiumWebBrowser

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть приложение WPF NetCore5.0 (MVVM Caliburn.Micro)

Нужен контрол с экранной клавиатурой, для ввода в элемент ChromiumWebBrowser.
Т.е.  ChromiumWebBrowser загрузил нужный сайт, в поля сайта нужен ввод через экранную клавиатуру,
Т.е. хорошо бы просто иметь экранную клаву которая работает как обычная клавиатура, т.е. события нажатия экранной клавы перехватываются и эквивалентны обычной клавиатуре.
попытался использовать
https://github.com/snmslavk/WPF-Keyboard-Control
Я так понял ввод с клавы надо байндить на какой-то контрол, а как сделать просто подмену клавиатуры?

Comment: При нажатии на клаву можно отправлять ввод в Win32 API `keybd_event` или `SendInput`. Если не хочется заморачиваться, есть NuGet пакет InputSimulator.

Comment: Я так понял это в code behind лучше сделать, т.е. событие нажатия кнопки, и в обработчике это пробросить на InputSimulator? попробую, Спавсибо

Comment: TermControls:OnScreenKeyboard  - Странное поведение, событие KeyDown, KeyUp перехватывает с обычной клавы, если обычную отключить то с экранной тоже не перехватывает. Другие смотрел пакеты экранных клавиатур, тоже все не то, там идет привязка на тип контрола например нажали на TextBox она вылезла, но с браузером так не работает. Не знаете актуальных библиотек с экранными клавами, пусть даже придется пробрасывать события нажатия, но чтобы логично работали хотя бы.

Comment: Да и фокус теряется  внутри браузера у поля для ввода при использовании клавы экранной.  Получается только жестко ее привязывать можно к свойству контролов.

Comment: На Winforms помню просто добавлял контрол и все, а на WPF они рассчитывают на встроенную экранную клавиатуру я так понял.

Comment: Ну так, если ничего не подходит, соберите свою клаву.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1179202/373567

Comment: Попробую, спасибо.

Comment: Было бы свойство у элемента браузер за которое можно забиндится, чтобы принимал он данные на отрисованную страницу на элемент который в фокусе.