# MVVM. IsEnabled MenuItem

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, binding, wpf-commands

У меня есть меню:

```
<Button.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu Placement="Bottom">
                        <MenuItem Header="H"  Command="{Binding AddCommand1}"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="H1" Command="{Binding AddCommand2}"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="H2"  Command="{Binding AddCommand3}"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="H3"  Command="{Binding AddCommand4}"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="H4" Command="{Binding AddCommand5}"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Button.ContextMenu>
```

И есть какой-то метод:

```
private void Method()
    {

       
    }
```

Как в этом методе установить IsEnabled для последнего пункта меню?

Comment: Используйте `CanExecute` команды. Примеры: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1122753/373567), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1282902/373567), [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1179202/373567)

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.icommand.canexecute?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Xaml

```
  <MenuItem Header="H4" Command="{Binding AddCommand5}" IsEnabled="{Binding H5Enabled}"/>
```

В ViewModel

```
private bool _h5enabled

public bool H5Enabled 
{
    get=> _h5enabled;
    set 
    {
      _h5enabled= value;
      Notify(); //вызов вашего метода сообщения об обновлении поля
    };
}

private void Method() 
{
    H5Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Вы могли бы исправить ошибки в XAML и отформатировать код?